# Trying to rewrite _.where function in Underscore library

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, underscore.js

I am trying to rewrite the _.where() that does this:

where_.where(list, properties) 
Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

I'm having trouble accessing the different objects within the array thats passed as properties to the where(). How do you access the values of objects in an array and itterate over them?

This is what I have:

```
 var arr = [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
               {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
               {title: "Cymbeline", author: "steve", year: 1671}];
    var newArr = [];
    var where = function (list, properties) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            console.log(list[i]); // just gives the array again??
            if (list[i] == properties) {// this conditional should compare the values in arr and     properties
                newArr.push(list[i]); // if the values in arr match those in properties then the        respective objects get pushed to newArr
        }
        }
        return newArr;
    }


console.log(where(arr, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}));
```

What I end up getting back is arr[] and an empty "[]" when newArr is returned at the end.

Comment: First, define `newArr` within the function, not outside. Second, note that you compare the objects, so simple `===` won't work.

Comment: okay -- ill add newArr to the fxn but I don't know how changing the scope will make a difference here? how do I access the object values themselves?

Comment: To iterate over the properties of an object use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check that it's the property of the object and not an object further down the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP wants is filtering a list with configurable (ever-changing) conditions but a fixed mindset (algorithm) of how such configurations do influence the filter process.

Being clear about that, one can go straightforward, implementing a function that does exactly this ... building the filter condition from the provided `propertyMap` and making use of it whilst filtering the provided list.

Not knowing of how `where` should be implemented ... as `whereEvery` or as `whereSome` the above described main approach is very flexible in providing both variants that only differ in theirs usage of `Array.every` respectively `Array.some` ...

```
var list = [{
  title: "Cymbeline",
  author: "Shakespeare",
  year: 1611
}, {
  title: "The Tempest",
  author: "Shakespeare",
  year: 1611
}, {
  title: "Cymbeline",
  author: "steve",
  year: 1671
}];


var where = function (list, propertMap) {
  var
    keyList   = Object.keys(propertMap),

    condition = function (item) {             // where every.
      return keyList.every(function (key) {
        var
          property = item[key]
        ;
        return (!!property && (property === propertMap[key]));
      });
    }
  ;
  return list.filter(condition);
};

console.log(where(list, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}));
console.log(where(list, {author: "Shakespeare"}));
console.log(where(list, {author: "Shakespeare", title: "Cymbeline"}));
console.log(where(list, {title: "Cymbeline"}));


var whereSome = function (list, propertMap) {
  var
    keyList   = Object.keys(propertMap),

    condition = function (item) {             // where some.
      return keyList.some(function (key) {
        var
          property = item[key]
        ;
        return (!!property && (property === propertMap[key]));
      });
    }
  ;
  return list.filter(condition);
};

console.log(where(list, {author: "steve", year: 1611}));
console.log(whereSome(list, {author: "steve", year: 1611}));
```